# Write empty dataframe to CSV in disk using data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to write data.frames in R to CSV in a loop using data.table's fwrite. Some tables have 0 rows and 0 columns and data.table throws following error
`Error: ncol(x) > 0L is not TRUE`

My final question is how do I `write an empty data.frame using data.table`?

Comment: Do you actually want to write the (empty) csv or just stop the error from derailing your loop? If the latter you might want to look at just building in an ifelse so you only write the csv if there is data in the table.

Comment: @EmilyKothe Assuming each file represents some database table, then perhaps the OP's API expects a bunch of empty columns.

Comment: A Postgres table cannot have zero columns.

Answer (score 0):

The `fwrite()` function from the `data.table` package should be able to write a data frame with no rows and one or more columns:

```
library(data.table)

fwrite(your_df, "path/to/output.csv")
```

It is not possible for a SQL table to have zero columns, so it would appear to be meaningless for a zero column R data table or data frame to correspond to a table in SQL.

Comment: fwrite threw an error as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Also, I edited the question to shift the focus from SQL postgres to data.table's fwrite.

Comment: Yes, because you are writing a zero column data frame, which makes no sense.

Comment: Tim, I wanted an empty csv file to be written for an empty data.frame